# Where to find PL/SQL injection checking library/code

Tags: plsql

I would like to know whether anyone knows about a library or code that will accept a PL/SQL string and thow error if there is any PL/SQL injection. Most of the open source projects in the internet are created in PHP.

Comment: Do you really mean PL/SQL injection or just plain SQL injection? PL/SQL injection should only be possible if your code (e.g. a stored procedure) does not check its input values and therefore returns data that the caller should not have access to. This is not something you can check automatically, as the testing library cannot know what results are valid.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I am looking for SQL injection on the data input done through a windows form. I want to sanitise the data before the data is sent to the DB.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parameters, for example

```
UPDATE mytable SET field=:param WHERE id=:id
```

And then assign `:param` and `:id` to be the value that you get from the untrusted source (form value, url params, cookie, ...)

This also improves performance, and you don't need to parse anything to determine if it's injection or not. (Such approaches might have subtle bugs that you don't see, but the attaker will use. I mean you cannot verify that *every* possible attack, including those you haven't thought of yet, will be stopped by an injection-detection logic.)

Comment: +1 bind variables guarantee no injection will occur. A very nice discussion about bind variables can be found at Tom Kyte's website: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2320123769177

Comment: I have this approach already implemented in my code i.e passing value as parameters. My only concern is at the data input level, i.e the GUI where the user enters data. I want to sanitise the data for SQL injection before it is passed to the server. This is why I am looking for a library. I am using windows form for data input.

Comment: But it doesn't matter, if you are using params then nothing bad will happen. Even if the user writes `';DROP table x` in the GUI form, then exactly those characters will get written into the field. Nothing bad will happen. (Although perhaps it doesn't make sense for those characters to be in a field, no doubt there are plenty of other character sequences which also don't make sense e.g. "fdgkdfggj").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a very good reason to use both dynamic SQL *and* to embed strings in your statements rather than use bind variables, Oracle has a built-in library for this purpose. It's called `dbms_assert`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm for full details on this package.